# How do I return ALL entries that are singles

Tags: sections, elementtype, singles

I'm trying to generate a sitemap and wish to output all the entries that have a [section type](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/sectionmodel#type) of 'single' but can't get the the correct syntax.

All of the entries need to return 'single' for `{entry.section.type}`.

```
{# This query doesn't work but hopefully helps demo the above question #}

{% for entry in craft.entries.section({'type':'single'}).order('id asc') %}
    <url>
        <loc>{{ entry.url }}</loc>
        <lastmod>{{ entry.dateUpdated.atom }}</lastmod>
        <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
        {% if entry.section.isHomepage() %}
            <priority>1</priority>
        {% else %}
            <priority>0.8</priority>
        {% endif %}
    </url>    
{% endfor %}
```

*Edit:*

*This query does work but it's a slow **bad way** of doing it as it gets **EVERY** entry and filters after the fact:*

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.order('id asc') if entry.section.type == "single" %}
    <url>
        <loc>{{ entry.url }}</loc>    
        <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
        {% if entry.section.isHomepage() %}
            <priority>1</priority>
        {% else %}
            <priority>0.8</priority>
        {% endif %}
    </url>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's no such method available for `craft.entries`, at least it's not documented. But you can use [`craft.sections`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.sections) to get an array of section models and filter them with a conditional within a loop:

```
{# Get all Section #}
{% set sections = craft.sections.getAllSections() %}

{# Loop through all single sections #}
{% for singleSection in sections if singleSection.type == 'single' %}

    {# Get the first (and only) entry of that section #}
    {% set singleEntry = craft.entries.sectionId(singleSection.id).first %}

    {# Output #}
    {{ singleSection }}
    {{ singleSection.isHomepage() ? '(Home)' : '(not Home)'}}
    {{ singleEntry.dateUpdated.atom }}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: `{{ singleEntry.dateUpdated.atom }}` is returning an error:

`Impossible to access an attribute ("dateUpdated") on a NULL variable ("")`

Comment: @jnowland sorry, just fixed a bug with my code.

Comment: How would the code be amended to order the singles listed?

Comment: @AdamHopkinson you could try with Super Sort plugin

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing specifically to do with the question, but this post was very helpful in figuring out how to get all entries that are **channels**. Just wanted to share in case someone else came across this thread. This will return all entries for every channel.

```
{% set sections = craft.sections.getAllSections() %}
{% for channelSection in sections if channelSection.type == 'channel' %}  

    {% set channelEntry = craft.entries.sectionId(channelSection.id) %}
        {% for entry in channelEntry %}
            <div class="block {{ channelSection.handle }}">
                <div class="block-header">
                    <h4><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="block-summary">
                    {{ entry.summary }}
                    <p>
                        <small>(In {{ channelSection }})</small>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="block-footer text-right">
                    <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

As you can see I am using:

```
{{ channelSection.handle }}
```

To generate something like `myChannelHandle` which (could) is useful for creating hooks for css/js.

Hope this helps!